# Unexpected behavior with useState hook React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, closures

I have some experience with class components in React, but am trying to learn hooks and functional components better.

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";
import StyleRow from "./StyleRow";

export default function Controls(props) {
  const [styles, setStyles] = useState([]);

  function removeStyle(index) {
    let newStyles = styles;
    newStyles.splice(index, 1);
    setStyles(newStyles);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {styles}
      <Button
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          setStyles(styles.concat(
            <div>
              <StyleRow />
              <Button onClick={() => removeStyle(styles.length)}>x</Button>
            </div>
          ));
        }}
      >
        +
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The goal of this code is to have an array of components that have an "x" button next to each one that removes that specific component, as well as a "+" button at the bottom that adds a new one.  The StyleRow component just returns a paragraph JSX element right now.

The unusual behavior is that when I click the "x" button by a row, it removes the element and all elements following it.  It seems that each new StyleRow component that is added takes the state of styles at the moment of its creation and modifies that instead of always modifying the current styles state.  This is different behavior than I would expect from a class component.

The freezing of state leads me to believe this has something to do with closures, which I don't fully understand, and I am curious to know what here triggered them.  If anyone knows how to solve this problem and always modify the same state, I would greatly appreciate it.

Finally, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286505/react-hooks-with-usestate) post on SO is similar, but I believe it addresses a slightly different question.  If someone can explain how that answer solves this problem, of course feel free to close this question.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the most preferred way in a new answer as the previous one was becoming too long.

The explanation lies in my previous answer.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";

export default function Controls(props) {
  const [styles, setStyles] = useState([]);

  function removeStyle(index) {
    let newStyles = [...styles]
    newStyles.splice(index, 1);
    setStyles(newStyles);
  }

  const addStyle = () => {
    const newStyles = [...styles];
    newStyles.push({content: 'ABC'});
    setStyles(newStyles);
  };

  // we are mapping through styles and adding removeStyle newly and rerendering all the divs again every time the state updates with new styles.
  // this always ensures that the removeStyle callback has reference to the latest state at all times.
  return (
    <div>
      {styles.map((style, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{style.content} - Index: {index}</p>
            <Button onClick={() => removeStyle(index)}>x</Button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <Button color="primary" onClick={addStyle}>+</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-currying-14zcs?file=/src/App.js:0-752) for you to play around.

Comment: Ohhh..that just clicked for me.  Similar feedback to what @Mr. Polywhirl gave.  So instead of passing the remove function into each button discreetly, you are just generating it in the render for each element.  Very cool, I will take this approach in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the existing state of `styles`, so you will need to create a deep copy of the array first.

You can either write your own clone function, or you can import the Lodash `cloneDeep` function.

Add the following dependency to your `package.json` using:

```js
npm install lodash
```

Also, you are passing the length of the array to the `removeStyle` function. You should be passing the last index which is `length - 1`.

```
// ...

import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';

// ...

  function removeStyle(index) {
    let newStyles = cloneDeep(styles); // Copy styles
    newStyles.splice(index, 1);        // Splice from copy
    setStyles(newStyles);              // Assign copy to styles
  }

// ...

              <Button onClick={() => removeStyle(styles.length - 1)}>x</Button>
// ...
```

If you want to use a different clone function or write your own, there is a performance benchmark here:

> [*"What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51741812/1762224)

I would also move the function assigned to the `onClick` event handler in the button outside of the `render` function. It looks like you are calling `setStyles` which adds a button with a `removeStyle` event which itself calls `setStyles`. Once you move it out, you may be able to better diagnose your issue.

---

## Update

I rewrote your component below. Try to render elements using the `map` method.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";

const Controls = (props) => {
  const [styles, setStyles] = useState([]);

  const removeStyle = (index) => {
    const newStyles = [...styles];
    newStyles.splice(index, 1);
    setStyles(newStyles);
  };

  const getChildNodeIndex = (elem) => {
    let position = 0;
    let curr = elem.previousSibling;
    while (curr != null) {
      if (curr.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        position++;
      }
      curr = curr.previousSibling;
    }
    return position;
  };

  const handleRemove = (e) => {
    //removeStyle(parseInt(e.target.dataset.index, 10));
    removeStyle(getChildNodeIndex(e.target.closest("div")));
  };

  const handleAdd = (e) => setStyles([...styles, styles.length]);

  return (
    <div>
      {styles.map((style, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {style}
          <Button data-index={index} onClick={handleRemove}>
            &times;
          </Button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <Button color="primary" onClick={handleAdd}>
        +
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Controls;
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, but I tried Lodash and the same behavior still occurred.  I updated my removeStyle function to resemble yours.  I have never had to do a deep clone on a list, and have been directly assigning objects in the form of let x = object for a while with no issues.  When I console.log the newStyles deep copy result, I always see an array that is one less in length that has a length equivalent to the index of the "x" button that I clicked.  For example if I click button 0, the whole list is gone.  If I click button 2, only the first two remain, no matter how many I have

Comment: @Aaron alright, I updated the response to include an updated component.

Comment: I like the detail about the map render, thanks.  I don't fully understand what getChildNodeIndex does.  Is this for finding an element in the DOM and removing it directly that way instead of from the array?  And then you call that with the first div found?  Either I am really failing to understand the point here, or is there a simpler way of solving this problem?  Finally, I tried the code, and it does work swimmingly.  Thank you for the thought and detail!

Comment: @Aaron the `getChildNodeIndex` is called by passing in the parent (`<div>`) of the button and finding its position in the list of rendered `styles`. Once you have the index, you can just splice it from the list of `styles`. After it is removed, the `render` function will be called and it will no longer be displayed.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation!  I think my issue came from my failure to use the map function for creating objects, I really like this way of doing things actually.  Don't know why I haven't seen it before, it seems like the standard.  Thanks a lot for the great answer and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to understand what's going on here.

```
<Button
  color="primary"
  onClick={() => {
    setStyles(styles.concat(
      <div>
        <StyleRow />
        <Button onClick={() => removeStyle(styles.length)}>x</Button>
      </div>
    ));
  }}
>
  +
</Button>
```

**First render:**
`// styles = []`

You add a new style.
`// styles = [<div1>]`
The remove callback from the div is holding the reference to `styles`, whose length is now 0

You add one more style. `// styles = [<div1>, <div2>]`
Since `div1` was created previously and didn't get created now, its still holding a reference to `styles` whose length is still 0.
`div2` is now holding a reference to `styles` whose length is 1.

Now the same goes for the `removeStyle` callback that you have. **Its a closure, which means it's holding a reference to a value of its outer function, even after the outer function has done executing.** So when `removeStyles` is called for the first `div1` the following lines will execute:

```
let newStyles = styles; // newStyles []

newStyles.splice(index, 1); // index(length) = 0;
// newStyles remain unchanged

setStyles(newStyles); // styles = [] (new state)
```

Now consider you have added 5 styles. So this is how the references will be held by each `div`

```
div1 // styles = [];
div2 // styles = [div1];
div3 // styles = [div1, div2];
div4 // styles = [div1, div2, div3];
div5 // styles = [div1, div2, div3, div4];
```

So what happens if you try to remove `div3`, the following `removeStyly` will execute:

```
let newStyles = styles; // newStyles = [div1, div2]
newStyles.splice(index, 1); // index(length) = 2;
// newStyles remain unchanged; newStyles = [div1, div2]

setStyles(newStyles); // styles = [div2, div2] (new state)
```

Hope that helps and addresses your concern. Feel free to drop any questions in the comments.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-gagarin-90ngn?file=/src/App.js) for you to play around with and understand the issue properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I had a feeling something like this was happening but I couldn't figure out why.  Each div having a reference to some function closure makes sense.  If I want to always call the remove function on the current styles state instead of in the way shown above, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Updating & adding the most preferred way people go about it.